# Intellij formatter force single line if go to next line

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, formatter

Intellij formatter has something I hate very much and can't figure out a way to disable.

when pressing ctrl+alt+l to format code all my single line ifs without parentheses goes to one line

something like

```
if(true)
System.out.println("yes");
```

goes:

```
if(true) System.out.println("yes");
```

the multiline ifs with braces keep the original formatting but i hate very much this behavior... does anyone know how to change it?

Comment: I suggest looking in the Preferences dialog. Go to the Code Formatting section and select Java. Then look for possible options there that are causing this behavior.

Comment: no option fix what i want

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Settings/Preferences | Code Style | Java | Wrapping and Braces | Keep when reformatting` and enable **Line breaks** option.